# Implementing Wikipedia in-place quicksort pseudocode in Java

Tags: java, quicksort, in-place

I'm using the pseudocode called Lomuto partition scheme on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort. But I just don't understand what it is that I am doing wrong here. The array never gets organized (regardless of the input size). This is preparation for my final exam. My professor wants us to use this algorithm, but I can't just learn it unless I have an understanding of how it works by testing it.

```
private static void quickSort(Integer A[], int l, int r) {

    if (l < r) {
        int k = partition(A, l, r);
        quickSort(A, l, k - 1);
        quickSort(A, k + 1, r);
    }
}

private static int partition(Integer A[], int l, int r) {
    int pivot = A[r];
    int i = l;

    for (int j = l; j <= r - 1; j++) {
        if (A[j] <= pivot) {
            i++;
            int temp = A[j];
            A[j] = pivot;
            pivot = temp;
        }
    }

    int temp = A[i + 1];
    A[i + 1] = A[r];
    A[r] = temp;

    return i + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what else to say other than that you just didn't transcribe the pseudocode correctly.  At the beginning of `partition`, `i` should equal `l - 1`, but you set it to `l`.

Also, you're not swapping `A[i]` with `A[j]` within the nested loop.  Here's the correct implementation:

```
private static int partition(Integer A[], int l, int r) {
    int pivot = A[r];
    int i = l - 1;

    for (int j = l; j <= r - 1; j++) {
        if (A[j] < pivot) {
            i++;
            int temp = A[i];
            A[i] = A[j];
            A[j] = temp;
        }
    }

    int temp = A[i + 1];
    A[i + 1] = A[r];
    A[r] = temp;

    return i + 1;
}
```